# Different AJAX result from different machines (simple code)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery AJAX and PHP code:

**jQuery AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "ajax/registration1.php",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(request){                 
        if (request == "success")
            alert("registration1.php returns 'success'");
        else
            alert("registration1.php returns 'error'");
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    echo "success";
?>
```

It works fine on my localhost, returns "registration1.php returns 'success'", but not on the other machine which returns 'error'.

Any ideas what I should check? Thanks.

**FIXED:**

He fixed the problem:

> PHP is not being invoked when calling "registration1.php" directly,
>   which causes the ajax() call to fail. If I wrap the form inside the
>   Drupal framework, it appears to go through correctly.

I don't know why PHP was not being invoked though.

Thanks for the replies :)

Comment: what is the error? did you check the error log?

Comment: have you alerted `success` in both machines

Comment: @BookOfZeus I'm sending him new file with new error handling. Will let you know the feedback.

Comment: @naveen I don't know with the other one, it isn't here so I can't test it easily.

Comment: make an error callback like you have specified the success callback and see which on fires

Comment: It's fixed before I get the error callback *damn*. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you put

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

in your php file

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    echo "success";
?>
```

do ajx request like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "ajax/registration1.php",
    dataType: "text",
    crossDomain:true;
    success: function(request){                 
        if (request == "success")
            alert("registration1.php returns 'success'");
        else
            alert("registration1.php returns 'error'");
    },
   error:function(jxhr,resp){
        alert(jxhr.status);
        alert(jxhr.responseText);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is a problem with your path.

Check the path is correct. And then check it again, cos it's not.